# Showing 0 entries and search not working datatable

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

Can anyone help me on my code? I can display my data coming from json but everytime I use the search on my datatable it always give me a no data aside from it pagination is disabled and showing 0 entries even if I have a data on the table.

This is my code:

**ajax.js**

```
var url = '../../class/functions.php';

function show_employee() {
    var data = { action : 'Show Employee Table' };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: url, data: data, cache: false,
        success:function(data) {
            $('#show_employee_table').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include 'class.php';
    //include 'init.php';
    $data = new db();
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'config.php';

    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'Show Employee Table':
            $data->show_employee_table();
        break;
    }
?>
```

**class.php**

```
<?php
    include 'controller.php';

    class db extends Controller {
        //Get all employees
        public function get_employee() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_try");
            return $query;
        }

        public function show_employee_table() {
            foreach($this->get_employee() as $row): ?>
                <?php $data = $row; ?>
                <?php $employee_status = ($row['employee_status'] == "Active") ? '<span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="badge badge-danger">Not Active</span>';?>
                <tr>    
                    <td><?=$row['employee_number']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['employee_surname']?>, <?=$row['employee_firstname']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['employee_email']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['employee_contact']?></td>
                    <td><?=$employee_status?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="modal_edit_status('<?=$row['employee_id']?>')" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Status"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="modal_delete_employee('<?=$row['employee_id']?>')"style="cursor:pointer" alt="Remove"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="edit_employee_by_id('<?=$row['employee_id']?>')" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;
        }

    }

?>
```

**accounts.php**

```
<div class="card">
                        <table class="table datatable-button-print-basic">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Employee Number</th>    
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Contact</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th colspan=3 class="text-center">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="show_employee_table" ><!--content will go here--></tbody>
                        </table>            
                    </div>
```

Then I called the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready (function() {
            show_employee();
        });
</script>
```

PS: I called the show_employee function inside the document ready.

#show_employee_table (id of tbody)

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I don't see you using "datatables" anywhere? All you seem to do is output an ordinary HTML table. Where's the search, which is what you seem to be asking about?

Comment: Are you using your `class.php` somewhere?

Comment: <div class="card">
                        <table class="table datatable-button-print-basic">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan=3 class="text-center">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="show_employee_table" ><!--content will go here--></tbody>
                        </table>            
                    </div>

Comment: Yes, I'm using it @kerbh0lz

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64861068/edit) to include all relevant code and info. Writing chunks of code in comments aren't just hard to read, they are also easy to miss by other users coming to help.

Comment: Done editing my question @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Edited my question guys. Help me please.

Comment: For debugging purposes, simplify things, and once that is working, add complexities back. For your code, remove the AJAX and the POST, just use a straight normal GET so that you can use your browser and see error messages. Make sure your error reporting is turned on completely for PHP, and make sure every conditional has a last resort, such as your `switch` which should have a default that `throws` probably.